# Limits for the integral of a joint distribution

Tags: probability, integration

I'm slightly confused on how to calculate the limits of a joint probabibilty distribution (continous case). For example, the following question 
[image]

I'm unsure of how the limits for the respective integrals were calculated, and would appreciate if someone could talk me through how to find the limits for the integral in general.

Thanks.

Edit: I understand why the inner integral is from 0 to 1-y, but if I used the same principle to calculate this, shouldn't the outer integral be from 0 to 1-x? I'm simply looking for the highest and lowest values of x and y which satisfy each inequality given in the question.

Comment: Draw the square with corners $(0,0)$,, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(0,1)$. Draw the line $x+y=1$. The density function lives on the part of the square "below" the line $x+y=1$, so on the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$. Bow it should not be hard to find limits of integration.

Comment: If I've done this correctly, then y is limited from 0 to 1, and so is x. Perhaps I'm being naive but where does the 1-y limit come from?

Comment: It says "and $0\le x+y\le 1$." So below the line $x+y=1$. If we integrate first with respect to $x$, then for any $y$ between $0$ and $1$, $x$ starts at $0$ and ends when hitting the line $x+y=1$, so the upper limit is $x=1-y$. And then we add up (integrate) from $y=0$ to $y=1$.  That is not the only way we can find the double integral over the triangle, but it works quickly. Since it doesn't matter, I would probably out of habit integrate first with respect to $y$,$y=0$ to $1-x$, then with respect to $x$, $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me a bit. Why exactly (if we integrate with respect to x first for example), does the limits of y equal 0 and 1, and not 0 to 1-x?

Comment: One "mnemonic" you could use (not really a reason) is that if you go from $0$ to $1-x$, the final answer will be a function of $x$. But it has to be a pure number, namely  $1$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. I'll see if I can build up on this in different examples to get a solid understanding. I appreciate the help, thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. For some probability calculations, one needs a pretty solid background in integration, and definitely not only in one variable.

Comment: Yeah. I'm fine with integrating itself, its just calculating the limits that I seem to lose myself in. I earlier posted a question regarding limits of (non joint) distributions, and with the help of someone, finally figured out how to work them out for general examples, and then came along double integrals...

Comment: @Ftahir because it is the outer limit.  Basically, you're extracting all the purely $x$ information about the support into the outer part of the double integral, and leaving the $y$ information in terms of $x$ inside the inner part.
$$\iint_{\Bbb R^2} \mathbf 1_{\{0<x<1\}\cap\{0<y<1\}\cap\{ 0<x+y<1\}}\ldots\operatorname d y\operatorname d x = \int_\Bbb R \mathbf 1_{\{0<x<1\}} \int_\Bbb R \mathbf 1_{\{0<y<{1-x}\}}\ldots\operatorname d y\operatorname d x$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The region over which the density is positive consists of the set of all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ such that:  $$\begin{align*}  0 < x &< 1 \\ 0 < y &< 1 \\ x + y &< 1. \end{align*}$$  That is to say, it is the triangle in the Cartesian coordinate plane with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, and $(0,1)$, which we can see if we simply plot the lines $$x = 0, \quad x = 1, \quad y = 0, \quad y = 1, \quad x + y = 1.$$

So to integrate the density over this region, we first choose an appropriate order of integration.  The symmetry of the region indicates that it doesn't matter if we integrate first with respect to $x$, or to $y$.  If we first integrate with respect to $y$, then the *inner* integral is with respect to $y$, and the outer integral is with respect to $x$.  The outer integral then ranges over those values of $x$ that contain some point in the triangular region; thus $0 \le x \le 1$.  For a fixed value of $x$ in this region (think of drawing a vertical line somewhere between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$), the range of $y$ consists of those $y$-values in the region that are intersected with that line.  So the range of $y$ must be $$0 \le y \le 1-x.$$  This establishes that the appropriate integral is $$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^{1-x} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx.$$  If you switch the order of integration, then you get the solution you quoted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot for this indepth answer, it's helped me to understand the limits alot better. Much appreciated - I marked your reply as an answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could clarify " the range of y consists of those y-values in the region that are intersected with that line". What exactly do you mean by this? If I draw a line on say x = 0.5, would the y values consist only of the values such that the values are from 0 to the height of the triangle where the line intersects? Cheers.

Comment: @Ftahir192 Yes.  If $x = 0.5$, then $y$ would range from $0$ to $1 - 0.5 = 0.5$.  And when $x = 0.75$, then $0 \le y \le 0.25$, as you can see from the diagram.